# How to get actual error message from RollbackException

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Could anyone help me with my first big pet project? I have a Telegram bot that receives information (sum of operation in Big Decimal that not null and greater than 0) from user and then put that info into SQL table. The operation template described like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "tg_user_id")
private long tgUserId;

private OperationTypes operationType;

@NotNull(message = "Operation amount cannot be null")
@DecimalMin(value = "0.0", message = "Operation amount cannot be less than zero, please review provided arguments")
private BigDecimal operationAmount;
```

Operation conducted by **transactional** controller that works through the Operations repository. Since the controller is transactional, I'm not able to try-catch income sum validation error at the controller. The part of the source code of the controller provided below:

```
        @Transactional
    public void addIncome(long tgUserId, BigDecimal income) {
        Operation operation = new Operation(tgUserId, OperationTypes.INCOME, income);
        operationsRepository.save(operation);}
```

Thus, I need to deal with validation error at the Telegram bot side. Here is the part of the source code that actually conduct the operation:

```
 case(BotCommand.RespAddIncome):
                      try {
                       log.debug("Income add command started");
                       operations.addIncome(message.getChatId(), new BigDecimal(message.getText())); //this part translates UId and the message with the sum received from the user to the controller
                       newsm.setText(BotCommand.StatusIncomeAdded); //this part forms success message that would be returned to the user
                       newsm.setReplyMarkup(getKeyboard());
                       log.debug("Income add command finished");
                   }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                           newsm.setText(e.getMessage()); //this part supposed to form an error message that would be return to user
                           log.debug(e.getMessage());
                     }
                       break;
```

In case user provides wrong argument (e.g. "-10") the app throws TransactionSystemException with the message "Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction" that is useless to user because this message did not contain an actual error description.
I can see the actual error in console as a part of the full error message

> <....>
> Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.tgbotyms.moneycounterbot.model.Operation] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
> List of constraint violations:[
> ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage=**'Operation amount cannot be less than zero, please review provided arguments.'**, propertyPath=operationAmount, rootBeanClass=class com.tgbotyms.moneycounterbot.model.Operation, messageTemplate=**'Operation amount cannot be less than zero, please review provided arguments.'**}
> <....>

Could someone please explain how to get this actual error message from TransactionSystemException in order to retranslate it to user?

*p.s. Since I need to learn only the principle of dealing with this kind of issue, in order to make it easier to read I've provided only involved part of code. If you want to see the whole app's source code, you can find it at [my GitHub](https://github.com/Markedo/moneycounterbot)*

Comment: This is part of the JSR validation spec, that the constraint violations are wrapped in a ConstraintViolationException, which is intern marked as the cause of the RollbackException (and possibly others). You'll have to call exception.getCause() possibly recursively, to get at the underlying causes of your rollback. In this case, you'd then have to call getConstraintViolations() on the ConstraintViolationException to get the list of constraint violations from the java validator

Comment: here's an article about that matter: https://www.baeldung.com/java-exception-root-cause